# Azure Functions still “Cold Start” in Consumption plan when keep alive request sent per 4 mins

Tags: .net, .net-core, azure-functions

I already read [Understanding Serverless Cold Start | Azure App Service Team Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2018/02/07/understanding-serverless-cold-start/) article.  One the the comments said **You can avoid cold start in consumption plan also by calling function from Azure Logic app in every 4 mins interval.**

I was trying to make 1 request per 4 minutes to one function of my app but this doesn’t always works. It sometimes still cold start.  I know it's a hack.  Is there any better way to ensure App always running when using Consumption plan?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I tried to answer this question in my article [Cold Starts Beyond First Request in Azure Functions](https://mikhail.io/2018/05/azure-functions-cold-starts-beyond-first-load/).

In short, there doesn't seem to be a way to avoid cold starts completely. Keep alive calls will make the life span of a given instance longer, but it won't make it indefinitely long.

For now, Cold Starts seem to be a genuine issues of FaaS implementations, they get optimized over time, but probably you won't be able to reduce them to 0.

Answer (score 5):

According to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#how-the-consumption-plan-works), we could use **Event Grid trigger** to avoid cold-start delay.

> **Note**
>
> When you're using a blob trigger on a Consumption plan, there can be up to a 10-minute delay in processing new blobs if a function app has gone idle. After the function app is running, blobs are processed immediately. To avoid this cold-start delay, use an App Service plan with Always On enabled, or use the Event Grid trigger.

For more details to avoid cold-start delay, refer to the two articles, [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#trigger) and [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid).

Comment: I'm more concerned with HTTP Trigger.  Does the **Event Grid trigger** helps?

Comment: Do you know why **Event Grid trigger** can avoid cold-start issue?

Comment: The Azure Event Grid is an event-driven Pub/Sub model, where an EventGridTrigger represents a subscriber to this model. Basically, it is a HttpTrigger with an event message validation. Subscribing to the source interest is via the subscription with a WebHook endpointUrl. the following link shows implementation of the HttpTrigger as an Event Grid Trigger, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid#use-an-http-trigger-as-an-event-grid-trigger

Comment: This has nothing to do with Event Grid. The reason the function avoids a cold start is because it's using an App Service plan, not a Consumption-based plan.