# Azure Functions unexplained cold starts

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions

In a microservice architecture running on Azure Functions v2 with a consumption plan, we are observing cold starts on services that we cannot explain. These cold starts occur frequently, sometimes within the same minute. Each one introduces a delay of 5-10 seconds. Since these services implement an HTTP-based API, this delay is visible to the end user interface.

We are expecting cold starts when a service has been idle for over 20 minutes or when it's scaling out while experiencing a high load, but every service is warmed up (called every minute or so) and experiences a very light load (under 5%).

We cannot find anything useful in the Application Insights logs.

What could be causing these cold starts? What other information could we gather to help us pinpoint the cause?

**Update 1**
All services are written in C#.

**Update 2**
Every service is in its own consumption plan, if that's relevant.

Comment: which language are you using ?

Comment: We are using C#

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50734965/6150264

Comment: Do you have startup logic in there?

Comment: Looks like you need to upgrade to a premium plan to get [pre-warmed instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-premium-plan#pre-warmed-instances) in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked in the "Platform Features" tab

Then [image: Diagnose and Solve Problems]

You may find evidence of exceptions and other hidden issues in there.

Exceptions don't show up in AppInsights if they result in a restart.